# Mock with void method causes 'local class name incompatible with stream class name "void"' when de-/serialized via Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, mockito

When trying to create a test for an application using Spark I face the following error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: java.lang.Void; local class name incompatible with stream class name "void"
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
```

This only happens if I mock some classes that have `void` methods that would be invoked at some point during the run of the unit-under-testing.

E.g. my code is:

```
public class MyTest {

    private MyClass uut;

    private Writer writer;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Dataset<Row>> rowCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);

        writer = mock(Writer.class);
        uut = new MyClass(writer);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // given

        // when
        uut.process();

        // then
        verify(writer, times(2)).write(rowCaptor.capture());
        List<Dataset<Row>> result = rowCaptor.getAllValues();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way that Mockito serializes its internal proxy classes. That only has a negative effect if the tasks / jobs you run within spark actually get serialized and deserialized.

In `org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask#runTask` the task is deserialized. What Spark basically does at that point is:

```
new JavaDeserializationStream(new ByteBufferInputStream(ByteBuffer.wrap(this.taskBinary.value())), ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).objIn.readObject()
```

which produces the exact error message vs.

```
new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.taskBinary.value())).readObject()
```

which *would* work and parse the object properly.

In particular there seems to be a mismatch between how Java / Spark expects `void` methods to be serialized vs. what Mockito actually does: `"java.lang.Void"` / `"Void"` vs. `"void"`.

Luckily Mockito lets you specify the way it serializes its mocks:

```
MockSettings mockSettings = Mockito.withSettings().serializable(SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS);
writer = mock(Writer.class, mockSettings);
```

After this change the test should work.

---

Note that `verify` calls for example are tricky / will not work as expected if the mock got serialized, sent to somewhere, deserialized and then used again. The invocations on the mock will not be visible to the original `writer`.